# How to hide tabs in ionic2

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

Is it possible to remove tabs in ionic 2, My main component is as follows

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Dash"> </ion-tab>
</ion-tab>
```

if I give   It gives error saying

Can't bind to 'show' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-tabs'

Comment: Try it, <ion-tabs *ngIf="false">

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: Hmm, just try by adding hidden="true" (when bind, change hidden to [hidden])

Comment: now tab1Root page is also hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully hide tab bar on a specific page.

First give an id to the  component:

Then handle showing/hiding like this:

```
{
    templateUrl: '...',
})
export class PageWithoutTabBar
{

    constructor()
    {

        this.tabBarElement = document.querySelector('#tabs ion-tabbar-section');

    }

    ionViewDidEnter()
    {

this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'none';

    }

    ionViewWillLeave()
    {

        this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'block';

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ionic 3, try

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tab 2" tabIcon="contacts" show=false></ion-tab >
```